# Harmonicity is a local property?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Why does harmonicity in a neighborhood of every point imply harmonicity on the entire domain? Is it a trivial fact? Is there an easy way to show it?

Comment: What is the definition of being harmonic?

Comment: Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$. A function $h:G\to \mathbb{R}$ is called harmoniic if  $h\in C^2(G)$ and $\Delta h=0$ in $G.@Mariano

Comment: ok. And what happens if you try to show that a function which is harmonic locally is harmonic in its whole domain?

Comment: @mariano If we take some arbitrary point of then domain then $\Delta h=0$ in a neighborhood of it. specially in the point itself., therefore the function is harmonic in all of the domain? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Please write a complete answer.